# Why are my cinnamon rolls turning into toffee?

Tags: baking

I'm following a recipe and following it exactly, and when I finish, instead of being gooey-delicious, the cinnamon-sugar in my cinnamon rolls comes out like 'stick to your teeth' tacky goo.  It's delicious, but the wrong consistency. What could be causing that?

Comment: What is this recipe you're following?

Comment: Do you have an oven thermometer? It's possible your temp is too high and you're overcooking.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the recipe, I would have to guess that your fat to sugar ratio is off on the cinnamon sugar.

Sounds like your sugar is caramalizing... Try uping the amount of fat you are using in your sugar mix.